# Need help in constructing SQL SELECT statement to get "top 10 x"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this **Points** table:

```
===========================================
FIELD           :      TYPE
===========================================
id                 int(11)
user_id            int(11)
value              int(11)
type               enum('add','subtract')
timestamp          int(11)
===========================================
```

Basically this table stores records of user points.

Now my question is: **How do I get the top 10 users with the highest amount of total points?**

**Note:** I have been told to change my schema -- drop the 'type' field and put positive and  negative values for the 'value' field. I just want to know if I could achieve the desired query using the current schema.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can definitely do it with your schema. No need to change it.

Comment: you can do it with your schema but it'd be "more optimized" if you do like you've been suggested to.

Comment: @RedFilter Tried biziclop's answer and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM( IF(`type`='add',+1,-1) * `value`) AS user_points
FROM Points
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY SUM( IF(`type`='add',+1,-1) * `value`) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd207/1

Alternative, maybe faster, maybe not, the trick is moving out the `SUM(IF())` part from the inner query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd207/9

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  SUM( IF(`type`='add',+1,-1) * `valuesum`)
FROM (
      SELECT
        user_id,
        `type`,
        SUM(`value`) AS `valuesum`
      FROM     Points
      GROUP BY user_id, `type`
     ) AS p
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY SUM( IF(`type`='add',+1,-1) * `valuesum`) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Probably both solution have to do a full table scan to summarize everything, so this situation might be a good candidate for some wise denormalization (collecting sums per users in another table, for example).

Comment: The basic idea is right, but you shouldn't use `*` with `GROUP BY`, and the `ORDER BY` should be `DESC`.